# How to delete records from Child table and Parent table in a single query?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a master table and a details table.
On delete cascade is **not** specified.

I want delete child record as well as master record in a single query.

Suppose I want to delete EmployeeDetails and Employee record where EmpID=20 using a single query.

Is it possible?

Please help.

Comment: Why not set the cascading delete?  This is exactly the purpose of it.

Comment: Why not activate the cascade delete trigger from parent to child? Is there some specific reason why you don't have it enabled? With the rule enabled, deleting Employee record #20 would then also delete any rows in EmployeeDetails where the cascade rule applied...

Comment: It can be done in MySQL (`DELETE parenttable, childtable FROM parenttable JOIN childtable...`), but not in ANSI SQL or T-SQL as far as I know. There are cases (non parent/child-based) where it's useful but a cascade wouldn't be suitable. Of course, there's always transactions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you cannot do it in a single query unless you have `cascade delete` turned on or you have a `trigger` on the PK table that will delete the FK table rows for that relationship

Answer (score 2):

There is no construct in SQL that allows you to delete from two tables in a singe command. You can do that in a single "batch" or in a transaction (which will be preferable).

Answer (score 1):

you could add a trigger on the child table to delete any other children and then the parent.  This is not "technically" a single statement, but your application only needs to issue a single DELETE and it is all done for you.